# Bukkit - How can I create a .replace in an item lore (String list)

Tags: java, plugins, replace, minecraft, bukkit

So I am trying to create a custom feature for my minecraft server, and one of the things that I am needing to do is to replace %CommonPackages% with an integer that is limited to a player in the config (I know how do to all of the config side of things, just not how to do the replacement in the string list.) Below is the code for setting the item in the inventory:

```
ItemStack common = new ItemStack(Material.INK_SACK);
common.setDurability((byte) 8);
ItemMeta commonMeta = common.getItemMeta();
commonMeta.setLore(Main.pl.getFileControl().getConfig().getStringList("Backpacks.White.Common.Lore")); //Getting the custom config file for the lore
common.setItemMeta(commonMeta);

inv.setItem(10, common);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setLore` method takes a `List<String>` as an argument. You can map that list to replace any of the strings you want before setting it to the lore:

```
List<String> lore = Main.pl.getFileControl().getConfig().getStringList("Backpacks.White.Common.Lore");

List<String> replacedLore = lore.stream().map(s -> s.replace("%VARIABLE%", "XXX")).collect(Collectors.toList());

commonmeta.setLore(replacedLore);
```

This way you'll replace all instances of %VARIABLE% inside the lore before setting it to the item